# how to add primevue css files to JHipster Project

Tags: vue.js, jhipster, primevue

I am trying to add primevue to my jhister with vue.js application. And I am following these steps.

**1- run these comments**

```
npm install primevue --save
npm install primeicons --save
```

**2- add them to my vendor.scss**

```
@import '~primevue/resources/primevue.min.css';
@import '~primevue/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css';
@import '~primeicons/primeicons.css';
```

**3- when I run npm start command. I am getting these error.**

```
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??ref--9-2!./
node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--9-3!./src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: Failed to find 'node_modules/primevue/resources/primevue.min.css'
  in [
    C:\work\workspace\aymer workspace\fiyatkolay\fiyatkolayweb\src\main\webapp\content\scss
  ]
    at resolveModule.catch.catch (C:\work\workspace\aymer workspace\fiyatkolay\fiyatkolayweb\node_modules\postcss-import\lib\resolve-id.js:35:13)
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss 4:14-231 14:3-18:5 15:22-239
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/main.ts
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9060 ./src/main/webapp/app/main.ts
```

how can I integrate primevue with my jhipster app. 
Thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not very experienced with Vue but the [official documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/#/setup) examples import the CSS files directly. I checked [primevue-quickstart](https://github.com/primefaces/primevue-quickstart) and integrated both libraries successfully that way.

**1. Install `primevue` and  `primeicons`**

Open a terminal and execute the following command if you are using npm:

```
npm i primevue primeicons
```

Or the following if you are using yarn:

```
yarn add primevue primeicons
```

**2. Add the required CSS files**

Open your `main.ts` file and add the following lines near the top:

```js
import 'primevue/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css';
import 'primevue/resources/primevue.min.css';
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';
```

**3. Import the components you want to use**

You can add the following lines of code to your `main.ts` file if you want all the [PrimeVue](https://primefaces.org/primevue/#/) components to be globally available. Or add them to `[component-name].component.ts` (e.g. `home.component.ts`) if you only want to make them available in a specific view.

```js
import Button from 'primevue/button';
Vue.component('Button', Button);
```

**4. Use the PrimeVue component in your view**

Open your `[component-name].vue` (e.g. `home.vue`) file and start using the UI component by adding the HTML markup. I imported the `Button` component so in my case it's something like this:

```html
<Button label="Click" icon="pi pi-check" />
```

I'm pretty sure we should be able to use both libraries the way you tried first, but I could not make it work any other way.