# JHipster + Vue : How to use with PrimeVue

Tags: javascript, typescript, vuejs2, jhipster, primevue

As title stated, I want to use [PrimeVue](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/) for my JHipster project. I tried to follow the exact steps from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60351266/how-to-add-primevue-css-files-to-jhipster-project), find the exact file and paste inside them, but some errors stopped the application from running:

```
 ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/main.ts 61:0-56
[INFO] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'primevue/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css' in '/home/pc/Desktop/JVue/src/main/webapp/app'
[INFO] resolve 'primevue/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css' in '/home/pc/Desktop/JVue/src/main/webapp/app'
[INFO]   Parsed request is a module
[INFO]   using description file: /home/pc/Desktop/JVue/package.json (relative path: ./src/main/webapp/app)
[INFO]     Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[INFO]     resolve as module
[INFO]       /home/pc/Desktop/JVue/src/main/webapp/app/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
[INFO]       /home/pc/Desktop/JVue/src/main/webapp/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
[INFO]       /home/pc/Desktop/JVue/src/main/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
[INFO]       /home/pc/Desktop/JVue/src/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
[INFO]       looking for modules in /home/pc/Desktop/JVue/node_modules
[INFO]         /home/pc/Desktop/JVue/node_modules/primevue doesn't exist
[INFO]       /home/pc/Desktop/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
[INFO]       looking for modules in /home/pc/node_modules
[INFO]         existing directory /home/pc/node_modules/primevue
[INFO]           using description file: /home/pc/node_modules/primevue/package.json (relative path: .)
[INFO]             using description file: /home/pc/node_modules/primevue/package.json (relative path: ./resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css)
[INFO]               no extension
[INFO]                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[INFO]                 /home/pc/node_modules/primevue/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css doesn't exist
[INFO]               .ts
[INFO]                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[INFO]                 /home/pc/node_modules/primevue/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css.ts doesn't exist
[INFO]               .js
[INFO]                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[INFO]                 /home/pc/node_modules/primevue/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css.js doesn't exist
[INFO]               .vue
[INFO]                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[INFO]                 /home/pc/node_modules/primevue/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css.vue doesn't exist
[INFO]               .json
[INFO]                 Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[INFO]                 /home/pc/node_modules/primevue/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css.json doesn't exist
[INFO]               as directory
[INFO]                 /home/pc/node_modules/primevue/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css doesn't exist
[INFO]       /home/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
[INFO]       /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
[INFO] 
[INFO] ERROR in ../../node_modules/primevue/button/button.esm.js 2:0-171
[INFO] Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue' in '/home/pc/node_modules/primevue/button'
[INFO] resolve 'vue' in '/home/pc/node_modules/primevue/button'
[INFO]   Parsed request is a module
[INFO]   using description file: /home/pc/node_modules/primevue/button/package.json (relative path: .)
[INFO]     aliased with mapping 'vue': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js' to 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
[INFO]       Parsed request is a module
[INFO]       using description file: /home/pc/node_modules/primevue/button/package.json (relative path: .)
[INFO]         resolve as module
[INFO]           /home/pc/node_modules/primevue/button/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
[INFO]           /home/pc/node_modules/primevue/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
[INFO]           /home/pc/node_modules/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
[INFO]           looking for modules in /home/pc/node_modules
[INFO]             existing directory /home/pc/node_modules/vue
[INFO]               using description file: /home/pc/node_modules/vue/package.json (relative path: .)
[INFO]                 using exports field: ./dist/vue.esm.js
[INFO]                   using description file: /home/pc/node_modules/vue/package.json (relative path: ./dist/vue.esm.js)
[INFO]                     no extension
[INFO]                       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[INFO]                       /home/pc/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js doesn't exist
[INFO]                     .ts
[INFO]                       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[INFO]                       /home/pc/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js.ts doesn't exist
[INFO]                     .js
[INFO]                       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[INFO]                       /home/pc/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js.js doesn't exist
[INFO]                     .vue
[INFO]                       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[INFO]                       /home/pc/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js.vue doesn't exist
[INFO]                     .json
[INFO]                       Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
[INFO]                       /home/pc/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js.json doesn't exist
[INFO]                     as directory
[INFO]                       /home/pc/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js doesn't exist
[INFO]           /home/node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
[INFO]           /node_modules doesn't exist or is not a directory
[INFO]  @ ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js??clonedRuleSet-1[0].rules[0].use[0]!./src/main/webapp/app/core/jhi-footer/jhi-footer.component.ts?vue&type=script&lang=ts& 1:0-37 2:24-30
[INFO]  @ ./src/main/webapp/app/core/jhi-footer/jhi-footer.component.ts?vue&type=script&lang=ts& 1:0-157 1:173-176 1:178-332 1:178-332
[INFO]  @ ./src/main/webapp/app/core/jhi-footer/jhi-footer.vue 2:0-71 3:0-66 3:0-66 9:2-8
[INFO]  @ ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js??clonedRuleSet-1[0].rules[0].use[0]!./src/main/webapp/app/app.component.ts?vue&type=script&lang=ts& 25:0-57 40:30-39
[INFO]  @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.component.ts?vue&type=script&lang=ts& 1:0-144 1:160-163 1:165-306 1:165-306
[INFO]  @ ./src/main/webapp/app/app.vue 2:0-64 3:0-59 3:0-59 9:2-8
[INFO]  @ ./src/main/webapp/app/main.ts 42:0-28 108:23-26
```

I also tried to find relevant documentation but seems like not many JHipster devs using PrimeVue. May I know how to run Jhipster together with PrimeVue? Any help and suggestion is appreciated.

---

**Edit**: I apologized for not adding more information. My Vue version is 2.6.14. Here is my **package.json** (I afraid the code is too long so I shared the important part):

```
"dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "6.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome": "2.0.6",
    "axios": "0.26.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.6.1",
    "bootstrap-vue": "2.21.2",
    "bootswatch": "5.1.3",
    "dayjs": "1.11.0",
    "vue": "2.6.14",
    "vue-class-component": "7.2.6",
    "vue-cookie": "1.1.4",
    "vue-i18n": "8.27.1",
    "vue-infinite-loading": "2.4.5",
    "vue-property-decorator": "9.1.2",
    "vue-router": "3.5.3",
    "vue2-filters": "0.14.0",
    "vuelidate": "0.7.7",
    "vuex": "3.6.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16.14.0",
    "npm": ">= 6.14.4"
  },
```

After that, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60351266/how-to-add-primevue-css-files-to-jhipster-project) by adding these codes in these relevant files.
This is  my **main.ts** (Also the code is too long so I just add what I added inside):

```
import 'primevue/resources/themes/nova-light/theme.css';
import 'primevue/resources/primevue.min.css';
import 'primeicons/primeicons.css';
```

Since me as a newbie wanted to try adding UI component, I chose **jhi-footer.vue** because it has almost no component so I can add freely:

```
    <template>
      <div id="footer" class="footer">
        <p>This is your footer</p>
    <Button label="Click" icon="pi pi-check" />
      </div>
    </template>

<script lang="ts" src="./jhi-footer.component.ts"></script>
```

My **jhi-footer.component.ts**:

```
import Button from 'primevue/button';
Vue.component('Button', Button);
```

Comment: the errors are self explanatory - it's telling you what line of your code causes the error, and what the error is - perhaps if you shared the relevant *code* (and your package.json) we'd be able to help you - also is this vue2 or vue3, you forgot to specify in your tags

Comment: Thank you @JaromandaX for suggestions, I already edit my question.

Comment: I don't see any mention of `primevue` in package.json - perhaps that's why node can't find it in `node_modules` - refer to [setup instructions](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue/setup) - you seem to have missed the first step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some hours, I finally integrate PrimeVue with JHipster. I am going to  post my findings here for begineers who want to do the same and for my future reference.

First of all, check your Vue version for JHipster generated application. In your project file, open `package.json` and find `Vue`.

In fact, despite I use the latest version of JHipster (7.8.1), it still suprisingly generate Vue 2 application. You can check [here](https://www.primefaces.org/primevue-v2/#/setup) for more information. I believe Vue 3 has different configuration.

After that, open `/src/main/webapp/app/main.ts`, add:

```
import "primevue/resources/themes/saga-blue/theme.css";
import "primevue/resources/primevue.min.css";
import "primeicons/primeicons.css";

import PrimeVue from 'primevue/config';
```

and the global configuration is done. Now in my case, I want to add UI component for footer,

in `jhi-footer.vue` , add any component you want. I tried to add `Button` component:

```
<template>
  <div id="footer" class="footer">
    <p>This is your footer</p>
<Button label="Click" icon="pi pi-check" />
  </div>
</template>
```

and in `jhi-footer.component.ts` :

```
import Button from 'primevue/button';


export default {
  components: {
    Button
  }
```

That's all. When you start the application it should render the components you add.

Comment: Vue 3 support in JHipster is blocked by dependencies, see https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/12558